# Horizontal Flatlist Re-Render changes ListHeaderComponent

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm banging my head on this one. I am using a horizontal flat list. And putting a view in ListHeaderComponent to act as padding. You can see it as a blue box in the first image below. That works great. Trouble is, when I refresh the flatlist from elsewhere in my app, the padding seems to break. See the blue box in image 2 below. Code below images. Any help appreciated.

OnLoad:
[image]

After props refresh:
[image]

```
<FlatList
    ref={(ref) => { this.flatListRef = ref; }}
    horizontal={true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={this.props.store.allBookData}
    ListHeaderComponent={<View style={{ width: itemOffset / 2, height: 200, backgroundColor: 'blue' }}></View>}
    ListFooterComponent={<View style={{ width: itemOffset /2 }}></View>}
    renderItem={({ item }) =>(

        <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={() => this.gotoBook(item)}>

            <Animatable.View 
                animation={"fadeIn"}
                easing={"ease-in-out"}
                duration={320}
                delay={240}
                useNativeDriver={true}  
                style={[styles.bookItem, { width: itemWidth, height: itemHeight, marginTop: itemMarginTop, opacity: 1, marginRight: 24 }]}>

                {/* cover */}
                <View style={[styles.bookCover, { width: itemWidth, height: bookHeight, backgroundColor: global.setBookItemColor(item.color)}]}>

                    <View style={styles.bookBindingHolder}>
                        <View style={styles.bookBinding}></View>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.bookCoverPhotoHolder}>
                        <View style={styles.bookCoverPhoto}>
                            <FastImage style={styles.bookCoverFrame} resizeMode={'contain'} source={Images.coverFrameWithTape}/>

                            {(() => {

                                //display cover
                                if (item.cover == 'temp') {
                                    //temp
                                    return (<FastImage style={styles.bookCoverImg} resizeMode={'cover'} source={Images.tempCover} />)
                                }else{
                                    //photo
                                    return (
                                        <FastImage 
                                            style={[styles.bookCoverImg, {opacity: 0.88}]} 
                                            resizeMode={'cover'} 
                                            source={{uri: item.cover}}>
                                        </FastImage>
                                    )
                                }

                            })()}

                        </View>
                    </View>

                </View>

                {/* title */}
                <View style={styles.bookTitleHolder}>
                    <Text style={[global.TextStyles.h3, global.TextStyles.darkText, global.TextStyles.alignCenter]}>{item.title}</Text>
                </View>

                {/* count */}
                <View style={styles.bookPhotoCountHolder}>
                    <View style={styles.bookPhotoCount}>

                        {(() => {

                            if (item.photoCount == global.maxPhotos){
                                var itemCount = 'Full'
                            }else{
                                var itemCount = item.photoCount + '/' + global.maxPhotos
                            }

                            return(
                                <Text style={[global.TextStyles.lightText, global.TextStyles.smallerLabel]}>{itemCount}</Text>
                            )

                        })()}

                    </View>
                </View> 

            </Animatable.View>

        </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

    )}/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say where the problem comes from even though there's a good chance it comes from your itemOffset that you apply as width to your HeaderComponent.

However, I have the impression that you can make it easier to define paddings, instead of defining a header and footer component, you could simply apply paddings to the content of your list by passing to your list the props: contentContainerStyle

like that

```js
<FlastList
    ...
    contentContainerStyle={{
        paddingHorizontal: itemOffset / 2
    }}
/>
```

but I think you should look in your calcul of itemOffset

Comment: To anyone that comes across this - Viktor was correct - I was calculating itemOffset in render. Once I put the calc in componentDidMount and added it to state - it worked perfectly. Thank you Viktor